# Can I use Java3D and OpenGL together in a same Java application?

Tags: java, opengl, java-3d

Does anyone know if I can use OpenGL with Java3D in the same project? I am currently developing with Java3D but I need some functions from the OpenGL library. 
Thanks.

Comment: What functions do you need?

Comment: I am looking for a function like gluLookAt in Java3D.

Comment: There is no need of calling gluLookAt, you can use Transform3D.lookAt(). You risk a driver conflict if you don't use at least Java3D 1.6.0 as older versions can use Direct3D under Windows. Moreover, you have to use the same OpenGL profile than Java3D. If you really need to use OpenGL with a scenegraph API, rather use JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation (I'm its main maintainer) which supports render delegates in JOGL or LibGDX (Brian, Xerxes and me maintain its JOGL backend).

Comment: I understand , thank you!